# Cell validation itens with default value if is blank - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I need to create a column with combo options to each cell but if user does not enter a value a default value must be inserted.

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this and see if it does what you want:

```
function onEdit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var editedCol = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();
var editRow=event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  if(editedCol==1 && editRow!=1){
  var eval=event.value
  if(eval =="Yes" || eval =="No"){return}
  else{
    s.getRange(editRow,1).setValue("Default Value")
  }}}
```